# Convert long to date in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2

I have long value in

```
$updatedTime = 1486270800000;
```

This value want to convert into date as format 2015-05-25 00:10:10

Now im trying this code

```
echo Yii::$app->formatter->format($updatedTime, 'date');
```

This gives as May 22, 2014. I want to be in 2015-05-25 00:10:10 format

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Try

```
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($updatedTime/1000, 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Above TimeStamp value will give `2017-02-05 10:30:00` ISO value.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asDatetime%28%29-detail

Comment: I given current date long value 1486270800000. for this, im getting 49068-00-18 9:00:00

Comment: Hi Mohaideen. I have updated the answer. Please check it now.

Comment: Those aren't "3 extra zeroes". It probably a microtime (with milliseconds included). Best that you divide the timestamp by 1000 first and then run the formatter.

Comment: @Blizz You are correct, It is timestap with milliseconds `strtotime('2017-02-05 10:30:00') * 1000`  giving `1486270800000`. I am updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your config file add this to `components`:

```
// other configs
'components' => [
  // other components here
  'formatter' => [
    'datetimeFormat' => 'php:Y-m-d h:i:s',
  ],
],
```

when formatting the date: `echo Yii::$app->formatter->format($updatedTime, 'datetime');`